# How do I correctly apply KVL in this situation, and why?

Tags: homework, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: image1]

I want to find v1. So I use KVL down the path from v1 to -3V.

I assumed the answer was v1+0.7+-3=0, so v1=2.3

But the actual solution was v1–0.7– - 3=0, so v1=-2.3

Why is this? Is it because the current is going into the voltage source opposite to sign convention? If so, does that mean the -3 terminal at the end should also be treated like a voltage source opposite the sign convention for the purposes of solving? e.g.

[image: image2]

So v1 + (-) (+0.7 V) + (-) (-3 V)=0, so v1–0.7+3=0 giving v1=-2.3 ?

Comment: V1 is 0.7 volts higher than -3 volts i.e. V1 = -2.3 volts. Don't use KVL, use your brain.

Comment: But if I was given a question that explicitly asked me to use KVL, would my understanding be correct?

Comment: You have expressed several different versions of your understanding so yes and no (version dependent).

Answer (score 3):

To apply KVL, add the load between v1 and ground to your schematic. Then make a *directed* sum of the potential differences; if I follow your direction of I, I get:

+0.7 - 3 - v1 = 0

That's because the direction over the load would go **upwards** to get back from your GND to the point labeled v1 in your schematic.

Comment: So if the question did not provide a load or ground I would just add a hypothetical one in for the purposes of using KVL?

Comment: Voltages don’t mean anything unless they are referenced to something.

Comment: @johnwick The rail voltages shown in the diagram are already assumed to be "with reference to ground." You could, if it helps you, add two voltage sources -- each with one end tied to ground and the other end tied as appropriate to the "loose ends" you see labeled with a voltage. People, quite often, actually remove the voltage sources themselves and just label the "ends" to make it "simpler." But "simpler" is in the eye of the beholder, I suppose.

Comment: @johnwick Applying a load to V1 and ground is an incorrect approach. In this example it just works because V1 is connected to ideal voltage sources. If the 0.7V voltage spurce were a diode or a resistor, and the load a 10Ω, then this approach would definitely yield a wrong answer.

Comment: spurce --> source

Comment: Eh. What does KVL say? _The directed sum of the potential differences (voltages) around any closed loop is zero._ So, you need a closed loop. There's no way to apply KVL without a closed loop, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

For applying KVL you need a closed loop.
As commented above, it is an incorrect approach to add "random" components to V1 in order to close the loop.
Moreover, it is not needed, because the schematic **is** already a closed loop.
Like @jonk comments, you should draw the ground symbols of the `+3V` and `-3V` sources. Then, it is not hard to find the closed loop (see red dashed box) and apply KVL.

Next, you need to find V1 … but with respect to what?
If it is with respect to ground, KVL is a quite dumb approach as it yields a result you could think of without using KVL.
If you need to find the voltage across the resistor of 10kΩ then KVL makes sense.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXxcJpm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>